# html audio element buffers badly after track change

Tags: angular, streaming, mp3, html5-audio

I have made PWA music player with Angular 5. Player can play Spotify, Youtube and uploaded MP3 files. Problem is with MP3 files. User can upload MP3 files to cloud. Backend for upload and streaming is done using .Net Core. After this user can play them using player. Player is using html audio element to play MP3 files. Tracks are in playlist so when one track ends next track will be played automatically. Audio element sends ended event when track ends and then I decided new track. It could be MP3 file, Spotify track or YouTube video. Normally it is next track in list but user may use shuffle. So next track is decided when track is ended. Everything is working well when using Chrome desktop browser. Everything is working also when using Chrome for Android and UI is showing all the time. Problem occure when user is using Chrome for Android and closes screen. Music continue playing current track well to the end and track will be changed to next one and starts to play. For a while next track continues to playing well but then it starts to stop and continue. It will be fixed only if I select new track using UI. So that stop and continue will continue when I open UI again. So it seems that audio element is buffering badly after audio source is changed new one without user interaction.

Related frontend code is here.

https://github.com/JanneHarju/MultiSourcePlayList/blob/master/src/app/modules/main/components/player/player.component.ts#L190

Should I use load() method or is it needed?

Comment: Try to stop your HTML Audio object on ngOnDestroy(), I saw that you unsubscribe from alot of things, but didnt see that u stop the player, so the music will keep playing untill the garbage collector will clear it. So, Try to do it manually.

Comment: Yes it should continue to playing. It is the point that user can close screen of phone and continue to listen music. So problem is that when track is changed when screen is closed music starts stop and continue after few seconds. I think it buffers track when i happend. But this buffering behavior is only occure when using Chrome for Android and screen is closed.

Comment: Ohh I see, so its a feature, I thought its your problem. So, after the current song finished and its continues to the next one, after the troubles at the start, does it continue? or it stops.?

Comment: When next track is started to play when screen was closed it plays fine at first but after a while it starts to cut. So it will continue to play but it is annoying to listen music which is cut all the time.

Comment: This is probably due to a problem with canPlayThrough event, you may find more information here: https://github.com/denisnazarov/canplaythrough , TL;DR - the event of 'ready' fire before the actual file is ready, its more sensed in mobile since lower speed of connection.

Comment: But why it works when UI is open. There is no cut then. I think there might be some oprimization for my app when is is background. My app wont get as much cpu and net  bandwitch when app is not open. So question is can I control somehow how Android is optimizing  battery or something. The case could be something like that.

Comment: You can try to load the next song while the current one finished, so you always have an extra buffer to be ready. shouldn't be too hard if you dont mind the "waste"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174953/discussion-between-janne-harju-and-daxx).

Comment: Ok. The main problem here might be actually in backend and my streaming implementation. Files are in azure file storage and audio element source is to my backend which download whole file and then starts to stream it. I didn&#39;t use dirwct file storage address because I think that was impossible. And it was if I use file storage instead of blob storage. Now I changed store for new files to blob and now streaming is more fluent than ever.